# Bootstrap, many text in button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Why I have many text in button, this text is cut. There's no return at line...

My code html :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:2%;">
    <div class="col-md-offset-10" style="text-align:center;">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-warning" role="button"><b>Chicken Research Area hhhhhhhhhhhhhh</b></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I display my html page, my button displays just "Chicken Resear"...

Comment: Its being caused by the "col-md-offset-10" of the parent div. Try resizing your screen to a smaller one, and you will see the full button text.

Comment: No because my button must haves 2 cols in weight... I want just returns at line when there is many texts